# Finding the correct order from a set of dependencies

Tags: c, dependencies, relationships, topological-sort

so here's my problem:
Input:
N, the total number of steps in the first line. Each step is implicitly numbered from 0 to N-1. A number K in the second line. Then the next K lines contain 2 integers each. Each such line represents a dependency: If "X Y" is in a line, then step X must necessarily be performed before step Y.

Output:
One line containing the steps in the correct order. If multiple such correct orders are possible, then print the one in which the smaller numbers come as early as possible.

Example:

```
3

2

1 0

0 3

1 0 3
```

Here's my code so far. I dont know how to compare the elements after sorting them so as to obtain the required format. Any leads would be appreciated .. thanks.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int n,k,i,j,temp,a=2;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    int arr[k][2];
    int ans[n];
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        scanf("%d %d",&arr[i][0],&arr[i][1]);

    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<k;j++){

            if(arr[i][0]>arr[j][0]){
                temp = arr[i][0];
                arr[i][0] = arr[j][0];
                arr[j][0] = temp;

                temp = arr[i][1];
                arr[i][1] = arr[j][1];
                arr[j][1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        printf("%d   %d\n",arr[i][0],arr[i][1]);
    */
    ans[0] = arr[0][0];
    ans[1] = arr[0][1];

    /*done[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        done[i] = 0;
    done[arr[0][0]] = 1;
    done[arr[0][1]] = 1;
    for(i=1;i<k;i++){

        if(done[arr[i][0]] == 0 || done[arr[i]])
    }
    */

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d  ",ans[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This requires a topological sort.  The equivalent question was asked yesterday. There's a tag [tag:topological-sort] you can search for inspiration.

Comment: Note that your sample data is conflated with your expected output, and the sample data doesn't match your specification.  Since there are 3 nodes, you can't have a 3 in the dependency lines.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to `#include` header files those contents are not used.  In this case the header file: `string.h`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 3) place appropriate horizontal spacing inside parens, after commas and semicolons, inside square brackets

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like `n`, `k`, even in the current context are meaningless